# What's the difference between Virtual-8086 Mode and Real-Address Mode in x86 processor

Tags: assembly, x86, real-mode

In wikipedia, the explanation of virtual 8086 mode is said that

> In the 80386 microprocessor and later, virtual 8086 mode (also called 
>       virtual real mode, V86-mode or VM86) allows the execution of real mode 
>       applications that are incapable of running directly in protected mode while 
>       the processor is running a protected mode operating system

I think this means that virtual 8086 mode can access to system memory and hardware devices.

And the explanation of real-address mode

> Real mode, also called real address mode, is an operating mode of all 
>       x86-compatible CPUs. Real mode is characterized by a 20-bit segmented 
>       memory address space (giving exactly 1 MiB of addressable memory) and 
>       unlimited direct software access to all addressable memory, I/O addresses 
>       and peripheral hardware. Real mode provides no support for memory 
>       protection, multitasking, or code privilege levels

I think there is no difference between them.
anybody knows it??

Comment: A simple explanation is that in real mode everything runs in ring 0 (supervisor mode) and any that interrupt or exception happens uses real-mode semantics. Code running virtual 8086 mode runs in ring 3 (user mode) and any interrupt or exception happens using protected-mode semantics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I think this means that virtual 8086 mode can access to system memory and hardware devices.

No, not really. In virtual 8086 mode there is also a protected mode operating system (the one that set up the virtual part) running in the background and deciding what memory and devices you have access to. Some of the devices might also be virtual, and simulated by the system. Old graphics cards, for example.

In real mode, the program runs directly on the real hardware - the way it did in the original 8086 (where this was the only mode). Even if there is an operating system, like PC-DOS, the application program still has unlimited access to all hardware and all memory. And can of course easily crash everything.

Comment: If my memory serves me correctly, it's impossible for a processor to switch from protected mode to real mode without doing a reset.

Comment: That was true on the 286, @Jeremy, so your memory is not completely failing you. :-) The 386 made it significantly easier to exit protected mode and return to real mode. Basically, you change the segment registers, disable the A20 line, and clear the PE bit in the CR0 register. No need for the ugly CPU-reset workaround.

Comment: I believe the reason for the popularity of the CPU-reset workaround was due to its speed (fast enough to be useful in a context switch even). Dave on Dave's Garage talks about this in a video where he cites that the difference at the time was something like 15 milliseconds versus something like 800 microseconds. Citation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8gOW0hFoJ0

Answer (score 1):

Virtual-x86 is Real-address mode that is working in protected mode.